# Is there some way of repairing/installing ubuntu-desktop from a .deb file?

Tags: boot, nautilus, apt

Hiya - I think my desktop is trashed. Nautilus is gone, and when I try to boot to Ubuntu I either get a never-ending login loop, or a black screen with only a mouse-pointer.

I think I need to reinstall ubuntu-desktop for ubuntu 9.10 - dual-booting with windows under Grub2.

Although I can connect to a LAN, and can apt-get update (I think), when I try to apt-get install, it gives the following messages, after about 20 minutes of waiting for headers etc.

[image]

So I'm figuring if I can just download a .deb file, and install that, I'll be getting somewhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: The error is a failed connection.  Are you sure you can connect to the internet and apt-get update?

Comment: are you even sure this is the actual problem? what other trouble shooting steps have you done and tried to prove the desktop is 'trashed'?  Perhaps start with a simple 'startx' command and see if the desktop can load at all.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have connection to the internet, that's why you can't install nautilus. Nautilus shouldn't be missing, maybe you played with packages and accidently uninstalled nautilus. If you're a beginner and want to save time, then I suggest you reinstall the system.

Also make sure you backup any important files before reinstalling. You can do this with live CD, or you can install over your existing partitions, but rememer not to format them.

good luck!